# SQL Pivot takes significant time difference between 26500 & 2650

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have been experimenting with EAV tables and their effectiveness in allowing for a dynamic amount of properties. Upon my experiments I have found that going over 26500 lines within the EAV table to be pivoted causes a dramatic change in time to pivot. I'm curious as to why this is and any ways to speed up this pivot process.

Below are images showing the query and the change in the execution plan.

[image]
EAV Table

25600 Lines:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (25600) *
    FROM _EAV_Data )
    AS SourceTable PIVOT( MIN([Value]) FOR Atribute IN(/*<Atributes>*/)) AS P
```

[image]

25601 Lines:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (25601) *
    FROM _EAV_Data )
    AS SourceTable PIVOT( MIN([Value]) FOR Atribute IN(/*<Atributes>*/)) AS P
```

[image]

Comment: one of your plans is going parallel, which depending on your system might be slower or faster. determining why this would happen isn't trivial, or possible without looking at the schema of your table or the statistics on it (neither of which you've provided)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). If you are supplying query plans, then please make use of [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).